Can fusion categories have an adjoint?
The question is a bit provocative, and in reality I mean the following:
Some fusion categories $F$ are generated by taking the irreps $R$ of a quantum Lie algebra at some root of unity (call this fusion category class $L$). Among those irreps is the adjoint $A$, and the adjoint always has some special properties $p$ (e.g. Jacobi equation). It is not too farfetched to assume these properties somehow "carry over" to the generated fusion category.
Thus: Given just the fusion rules of $F$, is there a "test" the $N^{ij}_k$ structure constants could be subjected to, so one immediately sees e.g. "None of the simple objects $R$ has the properties $p$ of an adjoint $A$, thus $F$ can't belong to $L$"?
Actually this question is sharper and "yes" doesn't follow even if some properties $p$ of $A$ carry over to $F$ - nothing hinders some $R\ne A$ to have property $p$ anyhow! Example: Let $p$ be "$R\ne 1$, and the Clebsch-Gordan series of $R\bigotimes R$ contains $R$." This is rare(?) but not exclusive to $A$: $7$ from $G_2$ also has $p$.
